blender assets pack gone
today my assets pack were showing (polyhaven) then after closing blender and opening it they were mysteriously gone and i have no idea how this happened, i haven't touched anything in the file directory or whatever that could interfere, i keep closing and launching blender hopefully it'll return how it was but my assets pack won't simply show up, what could be the reason behind this ? this is not the first time blender is having this type of bug, it's really frustrating but thank God, blender is free.



i'm dropping the screenshots to show that the problem is not coming from me ^^

How Long did you wait for? 8GB can take a while to reindex. Try this: Open Blender, wait for 1-3mins, then split the asset browser window into two areas.

I found the solution, Blender will not load the assets if I don't go to preferences and select one of the assets path and then click on "save preferences" which will trigger the loading (hopefully this will be rectified in the future) but now I ran into another problem is that after finishing the Nextcloud installation (ambientCG) when opening Blender it will load stuffs linked to the assets of ambientCG and then crashes without warning, eh... I guess I won't find anything here this just got too deep. Thanks for your msg @Leander
